# How to get null rows from first table while matching two table by using parameters

Tags: mysql

I'm matching two tables named as `teacher_evaluation_question` and `feedback`.
I want the records from `teacher_evaluation_question` table where student_id = 96 and where did not exists in feedback table

```
SELECT teacher_evaluation_question.* 
FROM teacher_evaluation_question 
LEFT JOIN feedback ON feedback.eq_id = teacher_evaluation_question.eq_id 
WHERE feedback.student_id = 96 AND feedback.eq_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY teacher_evaluation_question.eq_id;
```

This is Table 1 (teacher_evaluation_question):

```
+-------+-----------------+------------+
| eq_id |  question_set   | createdate |
+-------+-----------------+------------+
|     3 | QT1/&/QT2/&/QT3 | 2019-04-03 |
|     4 | K1/&/K2/&/K3    | 2019-05-01 |
|     5 | A1/&/B1         | 2019-03-05 |
|     6 | C1/&/C2         | 2019-04-23 |
+-------+-----------------+------------+
```

This is Table 2 (feedback):

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| id | eq_id | student_id | question | rating |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
| 13 |    26 |          2 | QT1      |      1 |
| 14 |    26 |          2 | QT2      |      4 |
| 15 |    26 |          2 | QT3      |      2 |
| 16 |     4 |         96 | K1       |      1 |
| 17 |     4 |         96 | K2       |      2 |
| 18 |     4 |         96 | K3       |      1 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+--------+
```

I am expecting result like this

```
+-------+-----------------+------------+
| eq_id |  question_set   | createdate |
+-------+-----------------+------------+
|     3 | QT1/&/QT2/&/QT3 | 2019-04-03 |
|     5 | A1/&/B1         | 2019-03-05 |
|     6 | C1/&/C2         | 2019-04-23 |
+-------+-----------------+------------+
```

Note: The value **student_id = 96** is a variable (It may change based on get request parameter $x)

Comment: Something not quite right here. How would you know that student 96 was supposed to rate a bunch of question sets? for example if student 96 did not exist in feedback there would be no way given your schema that he/she should, also if 96 rated k1 and k3 what would that do to your result.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the 96 is is a get parameter value. You may take it as a parameter $x or direct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT teacher_evaluation_question.* 
FROM teacher_evaluation_question 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT feedback.eq_id FROM feedback 
WHERE feedback.eq_id = teacher_evaluation_question.eq_id) 
GROUP BY teacher_evaluation_question.eq_id;
```

Comment: I did few modified this query like below SELECT teacher_evaluation_question.* 
FROM teacher_evaluation_question 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT feedback.eq_id FROM feedback 
WHERE feedback.eq_id = teacher_evaluation_question.eq_id AND feedback.student_id = 96) 
GROUP BY teacher_evaluation_question.eq_id;

Comment: Oh .. I missed that part `feedback.student_id = 96` @carte !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 96 has to rate all question sets in full you could start by tidying up the question sets , adding in 96 as a dummy column and then searching to see what has been/not been rated.

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t
(eq_id    int,           question_set   varchar(30),     createddate date);
insert into t values
(3           ,      'QT1/&/QT2/&/QT3' ,   '2019-04-03'),
(4           ,      'K1/&/K2/&/K3'    ,   '2019-05-01'),
(5           ,      'A1/&/B1'         ,   '2019-03-05'),
(6           ,      'C1/&/C2'         ,   '2019-04-23');

create table t1
(id int, eq_id int,   student_id int, question  varchar(3),  rating int);
insert into t1 values
(13   ,  26      ,      2   ,    'QT1'  ,       1),
(14   ,  26      ,      2   ,    'QT2'  ,       4),
(15   ,  26      ,      2   ,    'QT3'  ,       2),
(16   ,  4       ,     96   ,    'K1'   ,       1),
(17   ,  4       ,     96   ,    'K2'   ,       2),
(18   ,  4       ,     96   ,    'K3'   ,       1);


select 96 as sid ,replace(replace(question_set,'/',''),'&',',') qs ,createddate
from t
left join
(select student_id, eq_id, group_concat(question order by question) qs from t1 group by eq_id,student_id) t1
on t1.student_id = 96 and replace(replace(question_set,'/',''),'&',',') = t1.qs
where t1.qs is null;

+-----+-------------+-------------+
| sid | qs          | createddate |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
|  96 | QT1,QT2,QT3 | 2019-04-03  |
|  96 | A1,B1       | 2019-03-05  |
|  96 | C1,C2       | 2019-04-23  |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```